# Getting Html color codes with a JColorChooser

Tags: java, color-codes

Is there a way to get the html color code from a JColorChooser

My java Applet takes three colors from the user and averages them and displays the color

I want to get the html color code after they look at the average color

how can I do that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Write a method to convert a `Color` to a `String`.**

An HTML color code is just the R, G, and B values converted to hex and displayed as a string with a pound sign in front.  This is a fairly simple method to write.

```
public static String toHexString(Color c) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("#");

  if (c.getRed() < 16) sb.append('0');
  sb.append(Integer.toHexString(c.getRed()));

  if (c.getGreen() < 16) sb.append('0');
  sb.append(Integer.toHexString(c.getGreen()));

  if (c.getBlue() < 16) sb.append('0');
  sb.append(Integer.toHexString(c.getBlue()));

  return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: new StringBuilder('#') ==> new StringBuilder("#")

Comment: @user249654 I didn't realize there wasn't a character constructor!  I guess my code was just autoboxing it to a String.  Thanks for the catch!

Comment: @ErickRobertson +1 you can also use `Color.getRGB()` as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23556692/1048330).

Answer (score 1):

A slightly shorter version that relies on [Color.getRGB()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getRGB%28%29) :

```
public String color2HexString(Color color) {
    return "#" + Integer.toHexString(color.getRGB() & 0x00ffffff);
}
```

See [Hex triplet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#Hex_triplet) for more information about Web colors.