# A way of getting a corresponding hex colour code given a Color object in Java?

Tags: java, class, colors, hex, decode

I've inspected the Java class documentation for Color and found that I can generate a Color object from a hex code string `(e.g. "#FFFFFF")` using the `Color.decode();` method.

I would like to implement the reverse process for a project I am working on, but there doesn't seem to be a method already built in to the class for this.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
String.format("#%06x", color.getRGB() & 0x00FFFFFF)
```

The masking is used for removing the alpha component, in bits 24-31

Answer (score 3):

```
Color color = Color.BLUE;
Formatter f = new Formatter(new StringBuffer("#"));
f.format("%02X", color.getRed());
f.format("%02X", color.getGreen());
f.format("%02X", color.getBlue());
f.toString(); //#0000FF
```

Answer (score 1):

Read this: [Getting Html color codes with a JColorChooser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059133/getting-html-color-codes-with-a-jcolorchooser)

The answer has a method to convert a color to it's hex value.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way. Thought I just add this alternative.

```
// ARGB = (255, 255, 0, 0) (Red) 
// hex -> "ffff0000"
String hex = Integer.toHexString(color.getRGB());

// Reduced to RGB: hex -> "#ff0000"
hex = "#" + hex.substring(2, hex.length());
```