# How to find the name of the colour from the colour code

Tags: java, android

### What I am having:

**I have the hexadecimal name as**: `#000000`

**Now I want to programatically find out the name of that colour code which is** : *`black`*

---

### Question:

***How can I achieve this in the simplest way***

Comment: https://gist.github.com/XiaoxiaoLi/8031146

Comment: why dont you define `color.xml` with `color name` and `color code`.?

Comment: check this may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15113918/a-way-of-getting-a-corresponding-hex-colour-code-given-a-color-object-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapted from link Naveen mentioned, works using only native Android classes:

```
public class ColorUtils {

    /**
     * Initialize the color list that we have.
     */
    private ArrayList<ColorName> initColorList() {
        ArrayList<ColorName> colorList = new ArrayList<ColorName>();
        colorList.add(new ColorName("AliceBlue", 0xF0, 0xF8, 0xFF));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("AntiqueWhite", 0xFA, 0xEB, 0xD7));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Aqua", 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Aquamarine", 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xD4));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Azure", 0xF0, 0xFF, 0xFF));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Beige", 0xF5, 0xF5, 0xDC));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Bisque", 0xFF, 0xE4, 0xC4));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Black", 0x00, 0x00, 0x00));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("BlanchedAlmond", 0xFF, 0xEB, 0xCD));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Blue", 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("BlueViolet", 0x8A, 0x2B, 0xE2));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Brown", 0xA5, 0x2A, 0x2A));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("BurlyWood", 0xDE, 0xB8, 0x87));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("CadetBlue", 0x5F, 0x9E, 0xA0));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Chartreuse", 0x7F, 0xFF, 0x00));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Chocolate", 0xD2, 0x69, 0x1E));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Coral", 0xFF, 0x7F, 0x50));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("CornflowerBlue", 0x64, 0x95, 0xED));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Cornsilk", 0xFF, 0xF8, 0xDC));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Crimson", 0xDC, 0x14, 0x3C));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Cyan", 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkBlue", 0x00, 0x00, 0x8B));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkCyan", 0x00, 0x8B, 0x8B));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkGoldenRod", 0xB8, 0x86, 0x0B));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkGray", 0xA9, 0xA9, 0xA9));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkGreen", 0x00, 0x64, 0x00));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkKhaki", 0xBD, 0xB7, 0x6B));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkMagenta", 0x8B, 0x00, 0x8B));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkOliveGreen", 0x55, 0x6B, 0x2F));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkOrange", 0xFF, 0x8C, 0x00));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkOrchid", 0x99, 0x32, 0xCC));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkRed", 0x8B, 0x00, 0x00));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkSalmon", 0xE9, 0x96, 0x7A));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkSeaGreen", 0x8F, 0xBC, 0x8F));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkSlateBlue", 0x48, 0x3D, 0x8B));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkSlateGray", 0x2F, 0x4F, 0x4F));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkTurquoise", 0x00, 0xCE, 0xD1));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkViolet", 0x94, 0x00, 0xD3));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("DeepPink", 0xFF, 0x14, 0x93));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("DeepSkyBlue", 0x00, 0xBF, 0xFF));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("DimGray", 0x69, 0x69, 0x69));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("DodgerBlue", 0x1E, 0x90, 0xFF));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("FireBrick", 0xB2, 0x22, 0x22));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("FloralWhite", 0xFF, 0xFA, 0xF0));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("ForestGreen", 0x22, 0x8B, 0x22));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Fuchsia", 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Gainsboro", 0xDC, 0xDC, 0xDC));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("GhostWhite", 0xF8, 0xF8, 0xFF));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Gold", 0xFF, 0xD7, 0x00));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("GoldenRod", 0xDA, 0xA5, 0x20));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Gray", 0x80, 0x80, 0x80));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Green", 0x00, 0x80, 0x00));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("GreenYellow", 0xAD, 0xFF, 0x2F));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("HoneyDew", 0xF0, 0xFF, 0xF0));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("HotPink", 0xFF, 0x69, 0xB4));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("IndianRed", 0xCD, 0x5C, 0x5C));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Indigo", 0x4B, 0x00, 0x82));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Ivory", 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF0));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Khaki", 0xF0, 0xE6, 0x8C));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Lavender", 0xE6, 0xE6, 0xFA));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("LavenderBlush", 0xFF, 0xF0, 0xF5));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("LawnGreen", 0x7C, 0xFC, 0x00));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("LemonChiffon", 0xFF, 0xFA, 0xCD));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("LightBlue", 0xAD, 0xD8, 0xE6));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("LightCoral", 0xF0, 0x80, 0x80));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("LightCyan", 0xE0, 0xFF, 0xFF));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("LightGoldenRodYellow", 0xFA, 0xFA, 0xD2));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("LightGray", 0xD3, 0xD3, 0xD3));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("LightGreen", 0x90, 0xEE, 0x90));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("LightPink", 0xFF, 0xB6, 0xC1));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("LightSalmon", 0xFF, 0xA0, 0x7A));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("LightSeaGreen", 0x20, 0xB2, 0xAA));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("LightSkyBlue", 0x87, 0xCE, 0xFA));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("LightSlateGray", 0x77, 0x88, 0x99));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("LightSteelBlue", 0xB0, 0xC4, 0xDE));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("LightYellow", 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xE0));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Lime", 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("LimeGreen", 0x32, 0xCD, 0x32));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Linen", 0xFA, 0xF0, 0xE6));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Magenta", 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Maroon", 0x80, 0x00, 0x00));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("MediumAquaMarine", 0x66, 0xCD, 0xAA));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("MediumBlue", 0x00, 0x00, 0xCD));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("MediumOrchid", 0xBA, 0x55, 0xD3));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("MediumPurple", 0x93, 0x70, 0xDB));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("MediumSeaGreen", 0x3C, 0xB3, 0x71));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("MediumSlateBlue", 0x7B, 0x68, 0xEE));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("MediumSpringGreen", 0x00, 0xFA, 0x9A));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("MediumTurquoise", 0x48, 0xD1, 0xCC));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("MediumVioletRed", 0xC7, 0x15, 0x85));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("MidnightBlue", 0x19, 0x19, 0x70));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("MintCream", 0xF5, 0xFF, 0xFA));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("MistyRose", 0xFF, 0xE4, 0xE1));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Moccasin", 0xFF, 0xE4, 0xB5));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("NavajoWhite", 0xFF, 0xDE, 0xAD));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Navy", 0x00, 0x00, 0x80));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("OldLace", 0xFD, 0xF5, 0xE6));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Olive", 0x80, 0x80, 0x00));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("OliveDrab", 0x6B, 0x8E, 0x23));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Orange", 0xFF, 0xA5, 0x00));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("OrangeRed", 0xFF, 0x45, 0x00));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Orchid", 0xDA, 0x70, 0xD6));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("PaleGoldenRod", 0xEE, 0xE8, 0xAA));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("PaleGreen", 0x98, 0xFB, 0x98));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("PaleTurquoise", 0xAF, 0xEE, 0xEE));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("PaleVioletRed", 0xDB, 0x70, 0x93));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("PapayaWhip", 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xD5));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("PeachPuff", 0xFF, 0xDA, 0xB9));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Peru", 0xCD, 0x85, 0x3F));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Pink", 0xFF, 0xC0, 0xCB));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Plum", 0xDD, 0xA0, 0xDD));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("PowderBlue", 0xB0, 0xE0, 0xE6));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Purple", 0x80, 0x00, 0x80));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Red", 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("RosyBrown", 0xBC, 0x8F, 0x8F));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("RoyalBlue", 0x41, 0x69, 0xE1));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("SaddleBrown", 0x8B, 0x45, 0x13));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Salmon", 0xFA, 0x80, 0x72));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("SandyBrown", 0xF4, 0xA4, 0x60));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("SeaGreen", 0x2E, 0x8B, 0x57));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("SeaShell", 0xFF, 0xF5, 0xEE));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Sienna", 0xA0, 0x52, 0x2D));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Silver", 0xC0, 0xC0, 0xC0));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("SkyBlue", 0x87, 0xCE, 0xEB));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("SlateBlue", 0x6A, 0x5A, 0xCD));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("SlateGray", 0x70, 0x80, 0x90));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Snow", 0xFF, 0xFA, 0xFA));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("SpringGreen", 0x00, 0xFF, 0x7F));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("SteelBlue", 0x46, 0x82, 0xB4));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Tan", 0xD2, 0xB4, 0x8C));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Teal", 0x00, 0x80, 0x80));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Thistle", 0xD8, 0xBF, 0xD8));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Tomato", 0xFF, 0x63, 0x47));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Turquoise", 0x40, 0xE0, 0xD0));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Violet", 0xEE, 0x82, 0xEE));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Wheat", 0xF5, 0xDE, 0xB3));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("White", 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("WhiteSmoke", 0xF5, 0xF5, 0xF5));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Yellow", 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00));
        colorList.add(new ColorName("YellowGreen", 0x9A, 0xCD, 0x32));
        return colorList;
    }

    /**
     * Get the closest color name from our list
     *
     * @param r
     * @param g
     * @param b
     * @return
     */
    public String getColorNameFromRgb(int r, int g, int b) {
        ArrayList<ColorName> colorList = initColorList();
        ColorName closestMatch = null;
        int minMSE = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int mse;
        for (ColorName c : colorList) {
            mse = c.computeMSE(r, g, b);
            if (mse < minMSE) {
                minMSE = mse;
                closestMatch = c;
            }
        }

        if (closestMatch != null) {
            return closestMatch.getName();
        } else {
            return "No matched color name.";
        }
    }

    /**
     * Convert hexColor to rgb, then call getColorNameFromRgb(r, g, b)
     *
     * @param hexColor
     * @return
     */
    public String getColorNameFromHex(int hexColor) {
        int r = (hexColor & 0xFF0000) >> 16;
        int g = (hexColor & 0xFF00) >> 8;
        int b = (hexColor & 0xFF);
        return getColorNameFromRgb(r, g, b);
    }

    public String getColorNameFromHex(String hex) {

        int colorInt = Color.parseColor(hex);

        return getColorNameFromHex(colorInt);

    }

    /**
     * SubClass of ColorUtils. In order to lookup color name
     *
     * @author Xiaoxiao Li
     */
    public class ColorName {
        public int r, g, b;
        public String name;

        public ColorName(String name, int r, int g, int b) {
            this.r = r;
            this.g = g;
            this.b = b;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int computeMSE(int pixR, int pixG, int pixB) {
            return (int) (((pixR - r) * (pixR - r) + (pixG - g) * (pixG - g) + (pixB - b)
                    * (pixB - b)) / 3);
        }

        public int getR() {
            return r;
        }

        public int getG() {
            return g;
        }

        public int getB() {
            return b;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
 String black = new ColorUtils().getColorNameFromHex("#000000");
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to do that manually by mapping color code to its Name by creating simple HashMap object and map color code with specific names.you can get few color with names here

http://www.color-hex.com/color-names.html

+1 for code in above comment its using same colors as Link content lists

Comment: I read it and provided general Idea how to do that.the code which you shared using same Idea what I told mapping color code and name.btw the code using same color list which is in link I provided.

Comment: @KirtanPatel they dont want a general idea

Comment: question Now I want to programatically find out the name of that colour code which is but your answer is not programatically

Comment: @Naveen we are not here to write codes for others to do their homework and provide copy pastes to providing libraries to them git hub have it they can search by them self too.do communicate them by email if you want to provide such support.

Comment: @Devrath [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126029/java-color-code-convert-to-color-name) might help you

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

Define your custom HashMap to hold color name and color code Like :

**Set/Get Color Name :**
    HashMap colorNameMap = new HashMap();
    colorNameMap.put("#000000","black");

```
String colorName = colorNameMap.get("#000000");
```

**Set/Get Color Code :**

```
HashMap<String,String> colorCodeMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
olorNameMap.put("black","#000000");

String colorCode = colorNameMap.get("black");
```